# SQL Server 2005 - comparing char column with int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, debugging, sqldatatypes

I came across an interesting stored procedure and I need your help to figure this one out.

Basically, the stored procedure `SELECT`s with `WHERE` condition where the condition is:

```
WHERE SomeType = 2
```

`SomeType` is a `char(3)` column, which contains values like `'1','2','AA','AB'` etc.

When I run the stored procedure in SSMS, it fails with:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Syntax error converting the varchar value 'AA' to a column of data type int.

However, when I use that stored procedure through an app in Production, it returns data without any issues.

My question is, how is that possible?

Comment: Error handling around where the stored proc is called would be the most likely explaination. Doesn't excuse the fact that it's bad code (A simple `CAST`, or wrapping the '2' in quotes fixes it)

Comment: Yes,exactly... '2' should work.Else use a convert or CAST after SomeType=

Comment: I understand it is a bad coding and it will be fixed by '2' etc but it doesn't make sense how the SP fails in SSMS but succeeds in app that uses this SP.

Comment: Use SQL Server profiler and capture the query actually used when you execute from your app. It might be a parameterized query using sp_executesql with a char(3) parameter.

Comment: @hkf: I suspect the error handling is done on SQL side of it, not code? as if SP fails, the code will have no data to handle on. The SP itself does not have error handling within. Do you know anywhere else it might handle? or is there some sort of DB settings to allow mismatching data type comparison?

Comment: @James There is no way to "allow mismatching data types" afiak.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: The condition `WHERE SomeType = 2` is hardcoded and 2 is not a result from a SQL Variable. I did run the SQL Profiler and it does give me the whole statement but it is not much use as I'm blankly staring at `WHERE SomeType =2` and wondering how this is possible :)

Comment: Is it the only condition in the where clause? Are there joins to other tables?

Comment: Yes, there are other table joins in that statement.

Comment: Capture both actual execution plans and see what the differences are.

Comment: BTW are there any other `WHERE` filters?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I have limited access to production SQL Server and unable to run Profiler on that server but I am able to `SELECT`. The SP has dynamic SQL execution (statement made of varchar) but that `SomeType = 2` is hardcoded, not generated. When I run that straight off SSMS, it throws me that convert error. but when the app uses that SP, it returns all data without issues (obviously the ones with `SomeType = '2'`).

Comment: Yes, there are other WHERE clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in the comments that you have additional `WHERE` clauses not shown.

The issue may be different execution plans. e.g. suppose your real `WHERE` condition is

```
WHERE SomeType = 2 AND Foo = 'X'
```

and your data is

```
SomeType Foo
-------- ----
1        X
2        X
AA       Y
AB       Y
```

Then on one instance it might evaluate Foo = 'X' first leaving rows

```
SomeType Foo
-------- ----
1        X
2        X
```

Then it runs the `IMPLICIT_CAST(SomeType AS INT) = 2` condition against these filtered rows with no problems.

However if the order is reversed such that it first evaluates the `SomeType = 2` condition then it will need to cast the values `AA` and `AB` to `int` and the query will fail.

Answer (score 2):

The app might be calling the SP with different parameters, so that the bad code is never executed. Or the app might just ignore the error.

Comment: I will attempt to see the statement run on prod using profiler but I will need to find someone with access!

Answer (score 0):

Convert `int` to `Char` and I think it will work fine.